# Replace t=0.000000 by counting time

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I use this code to replace t=0.000000 by a counter (time=time+10) so at each time the code finds t=0.000000, it adds 10   and they become 0, 10, 20, ...
Any ideas how to get this done

```
import re
import itertools
counter = itertools.count(0, 10)
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in:
with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        re.sub("t=0.000000", f"t={next(counter):.6f}", line.lower())
        f_out.write(line + "/n")
```

Comment: So you want the line that contained t=0.00000 to be the same but replace the t=0.00000 with time += counter where counter increments with 10?

Comment: Yes, the file has more than 2000 lines of t=0.000000. What I want is when the code finds the first t=0.000000, keep it and when finds second t=0.000000 add to it 10 so it becomes t=10.00000 and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like that:

```
import re
import itertools
counter = itertools.count(0, 10)
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            re.sub("t=0.000000", f"t += {next(counter)}", line.lower())
            f_out.write(line + "/n")
```

count gives an infinite sequence of multiples of 10, sub replaces the old part with the new.

EDIT:

Just noticed you want different output, changing the string accordingly:

```
import re
import itertools
counter = itertools.count(0, 10)
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            re.sub("t=0.000000", f"t={next(counter):.6f}", line.lower())
            f_out.write(line + "/n")
```

Comment: I think yes but is not working someting invalid here  "t += {next(counter)}"

Comment: Look at my edit - the second version should be what you want. It replaces the old string with a multiple of 10 with 6 decimal places.

Comment: @Ch.I please add this as edit to your original question, the formatting in comments isn't great. I'll look at it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for your help